# How to include subreport from SQL query in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have few(around 30) static block and I have created subreports for it. Now I want to display subreports based on query output from master report.

In the query itself I have kept name of the subreport to load but when I am running the report I can see that the subreport is loaded but it does not display the output.

For example: If there are 3 rows returned on master report it will return report name something like this >>

1 SomeData Report1.jrxml 
2 SomeData Report2.jrxml 
3 SomeData Report3.jrxml

I am using the third column for loading subreport dynamically.

I have attached an image for the reference.

[image: Subreport name from query output]

Comment: Did you try expression with field? What problem did you face?

Comment: Yes, I tried expression with field but it didnt work.

Comment: It loads the report but it does not display the content of the report. The reason I know it loads up the report is because I tried with the wrong report name and it gave an error.

Comment: Issue got resolved after setting Data Source Expression to new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource() .

Thanks Alex for all the help and showing interest.

Answer (score -1):

The issue got resolved after setting **Data Source Expression** to **new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()**.